# A list of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any way that I could have some MATLAB object A, such that A(1), A(2), .., A(n) are all 3x3 matrices? I know that this would be easy in Python, but I do not. have too much experience with MATLAB. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You can use a [3D array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), so that you matrices are `A(:,:,1)`, `A(:,:,2)` etc. If the matrix sizes can be different you need a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html), so your matrices will be `A{1}`, `A{2}` etc

Comment: Please search before you post a question. The very top result for the search "list of matrices in MATLAB" is the Q&A I've linked here.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Struct](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) type in matlab meet your needs?